# ESB vs Yahoo Pipes

Tags: content-management-system, pipe, esb

I'm new to ESBs and wondered if anyone could help me out with the following. I want to build a system which takes data (i.e. RSS feeds, but could be any type of data/news source), pump them into a CMS system, have a content manager approve and, if necessary, tweak this content. Afterwards I would have the content manager select the channels to which he wants to distribute the content to, and then I would like the CMS to distribute this content to the appropriate channels selected by the content manager.

The way I see it is that there would be an ESB-like architecture between the data sources and the CMS, and then once again between the CMS and the channels to which to publish.

Is this a correct method of thinking? Or am I completely wrong in my assumptions?
Also, I wondered if I needed a full-blown ESB setup or could I just do with a Yahoo Pipes setup which transforms all incoming data sources into one feed which I pull into the CMS on one side, and a web service going out from the CMS, which can be called by the separate content channels on the other side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A piece of advice, don't complicate. You can use Event SOA, but I don't see the benefits you would get from it, because your case scenario is not that complicated, not to say that you only use Event SOA architectures with complicated requirements.  You  need to think ahead in the future, the SLA's (number of transactions, load balance...) only after that you know the constraints for your architecture, and you can make a decision on whether you need to build your system in a distributed way from the start or have just the base, as service contracts which would allow you to go the distributed way should the need arise. Distributing a system is complicated already, so before you think you need to do that, you need to know the SLA´s for your system, and lay a plan for scalability.